# How do I cope with negative steady state probabilities for a transition matrix of a markov chain?

Tags: python, numpy, negative-number, markov-chains, probability-theory

I am trying to calculate the steady state probabilities for a 30x30 transition matrix of a markov chain. It worked for smaller matrices, but for the 30x30 matrix I am getting negative values for steady state probability.

I suppose it has to do with the very low probability that one will reach the certain state, but it is necessary for my further calculations to let these values be non-negative.

This is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import operator
from functools import reduce
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matrix_5 = np.array([[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15, 0.6, 0.05, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.15, 0.0, 0.15, 0.5, 0.2, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.8],
                     [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.0],
                     ])  # Probability renting i returning to i and i to j --> sum has to be 1


def relative_throughput_pi(matrix):
    """
    This function calculates relative throughput from a probability matrix
    :param matrix: the probability matrix
    :return: A list of relative throughput values
    """
    a_list = []
    b_list = []
    for v in matrix:
        a_list.append(1)
        b_list.append(0)
    b_list.append(1)
    A = np.append(np.transpose(matrix) - np.identity(len(matrix)), [a_list], axis=0)
    b = np.transpose(np.array(b_list))
    return np.linalg.solve(np.transpose(A).dot(A), np.transpose(A).dot(b))


steady_state_prob = relative_throughput_pi(matrix_5)

print(steady_state_prob)
```

This is the result i got:

```
[ 4.84241126e-02  7.11444308e-02  2.97582619e-02  5.69155447e-02
  2.93757650e-01  1.45272338e-02  4.84241126e-03 -1.57653422e-16
  4.84241126e-03  2.42120563e-02  1.06716646e-02  4.26866585e-02
  3.55722154e-03 -4.96585198e-17  1.42288862e-02  6.61129831e-17
  8.92747858e-03  2.97582619e-03  8.92747858e-03  8.92747858e-03
  8.53733170e-03 -3.23435740e-16  8.53733170e-03  2.84577723e-02
  1.13831089e-02  1.46878825e-02  1.46878825e-02  1.46878825e-02
  1.46878825e-02  2.35006120e-01]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this and could tell me what I am doing wrong?

THanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong. These negative numbers are of very small magnitude (1e-17 - 1e-16) and are a result of numerical error of solving the linear system. The true solution is likely exactly zero. You can safely round these values to zero.